# What's the best way to make a Count Down Timer?

Tags: android, countdowntimer, android-timer

I am wondering if this is the best way to make a timer of 1 minute on Android:

```
 new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            public void onFinish() {

            }

        }.start();
```

Comment: Whatever way other than using a thread with sleep should be correct enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easy and very simple way

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

for more info see this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the onTick():

```
new CountDownTimer(60000, 60000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }

    public void onFinish() {
        //do your stuff here
    }

}.start();
```